# Why need "display:none" here in the code?

Tags: css, wordpress, display

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="row collapse featured-option">
           <input id="featured" name="featured" type="checkbox" style="display: none;" <?php echo esc_attr( $featured_disabled ); ?>>
           <span class="custom checkbox <?php echo esc_attr( $featured_disabled ); ?>"></span> <?php echo sprintf( __( 'Feature Proposal %s', APP_TD ), sprintf( _n( '(1 credit)', '(%d credits)', hrb_required_credits_to('feature_proposal'), APP_TD ), hrb_required_credits_to('feature_proposal') ) ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to edit this **wordpress theme code** to use it for my own website.
But I don't know why `style="display: none;"` is needed here.

When I erase this style element, I get checkbox on the screen
but the functions are not working as it should be.

What's wrong with this? Why need **"display: none"**?

Please help

Comment: it probably uses javascript to set a property, and uses css to simulate a checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance it is simply just hiding the checkbox.  When

```
style = "display:none;"
```

is used, the page will be displayed as if the item does not exist.  Meaning the layout of the page will not show a "hole" or something where that item is missing. In other words, the layout will not be affected by this.

The other way to hide something would be with,

```
style = "visibility:hidden;"
```

However, the page layout will be affected and the hidden item will still take up the same space.

Depending on what was trying to be accomplished, the checkbox could be hidden for different reasons.  It's possible that the programmer of this code wanted to hide this checkbox by default and then show it later on after certain events occurred.  Additionally, there are times when it is best to show and hide objects as you need them or don't need them rather than constantly recreating or deleting them.